# Basic components for building an offline app

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, server

I am very new to GIS app creation and am basically learning from scratch. I am not building the app but researching what would be the best components. These are the essential requirements:

1. 5km (area of interest) ability to zoom out and see whole earth
2. Refresh and dynamically update overlays
3. Interactive click to get more info
4. Display lat/lon on cursor
5. Switch between road/aerial/topo basemaps
6. Ability to host all mapping data on an isolated server that isn’t on the internet. The clients are on the same isolated network.
7. Service that provides standard aerial photographs.
8. Ability to add our own custom aerial photographs to the server as a new layer
9. No subscription fees

After some research I think for the basemaps the best options I could find was [OpenStreetMaps](http://planet.openstreetmap.org/) for the roads layer, [USGS Imagery](https://viewer.nationalmap.gov/basic/#productGroupSearch) for the aerial layer, and [USGS topography](https://viewer.nationalmap.gov/basic/#productGroupSearch) map for the topography layer.

[OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/) as the front end.

[GeoWebCache](http://geowebcache.org/) as the tile cacher.

[GeoServer](http://geoserver.org) as the tile server.

Am I missing anything or is there a better option available? From what I've read all these components can work together and there are methods to get OpenStreetMaps working with GeoServer. I know there will be a lot more to it but I am just trying to get the basics down so I can dive deeper into how they work.

Comment: Consider where you would put the data. Open source Postgresql+PostGIS are often used.

Comment: So aside from data storage do you think this would be a sufficient software stack to create a GIS app?

Comment: You seem to be seeking a review of your proposed stack with suggestions for alternative components which makes your question too broad for focused Q&A.